# Unexpected display error when trying to remove specific edges from network graph using Python, Mesa and Networkx

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, agent-based-modeling, mesa

I am extending the Virus on Network [example](https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa/tree/master/examples/virus_on_network) from Mesa. The current network graph is like this. However, I want to remove the edges from the dead hosts (black).

[image]

My attempt is within the `try_check_death()`:

`model_agent.py`

```
import random
import pysnooper
import sys

from random import randrange
from mesa import Agent
from .model_state import State

class HostAgent(Agent):
    def __init__(self, unique_id, model, initial_state, virus_check_frequency, chance_spread_virus,
                 chance_recovery, chance_gain_resistance, chance_virus_kill_host, chance_severe_condition):
        super().__init__(unique_id, model)

        self.age = randrange(101) # Later to be reassign by another module (AB, Edmonton, Calgary specific)
        self.sex = random.choice(['M', 'F']) # Later to be reassign by another module (AB, Edmonton, Calgary specific)
        self.urban = random.choice(['Urban', 'Rural']) # Later to be reassign by another module (AB, Edmonton, Calgary specific); later to be interact with agent location and link assignment

        self.state = initial_state
        self.virus_check_frequency = virus_check_frequency
        self.chance_spread_virus = chance_spread_virus
        self.chance_recovery = chance_recovery
        self.chance_gain_resistance = chance_gain_resistance
        self.chance_virus_kill_host = chance_virus_kill_host
        self.chance_severe_condition = chance_severe_condition

        self.days_of_infection = None
        self.days_in_hospital_for_infection = None
        self.infection_severity = None
        self.clinical_outcomes_from_infection = None
        self.clinical_outcomes_after_recovery = None

    def modify_chance(self): # a generic function that modify chance attributes
        pass

    def try_infect_neighbors(self):
        neighbors_nodes = self.model.grid.get_neighbors(self.pos, include_center=False)
        susceptible_neighbors = [agent for agent in self.model.grid.get_cell_list_contents(neighbors_nodes) if
                                 agent.state is State.SUSCEPTIBLE]

        for neighbor_agent in susceptible_neighbors:
            if self.random.random() < self.chance_spread_virus:
                neighbor_agent.state = State.INFECTED

    def try_gain_resistance(self):
        if self.random.random() < self.chance_gain_resistance:
            self.state = State.RESISTANT

    def try_remove_infection(self):
        # Try to remove
        if self.random.random() < self.chance_recovery:
            # Success
            self.state = State.SUSCEPTIBLE
            self.try_gain_resistance()
        else:
            # Failed
            self.state = State.INFECTED

    def try_kill_host(self):
        if self.random.random() < self.chance_virus_kill_host:
            self.state = State.DEATH

    def try_check_infection(self):
        if self.random.random() < self.virus_check_frequency:
            # Checking...
            if self.state is State.INFECTED:
                self.try_remove_infection()

    def try_check_death(self):
        if self.state is State.INFECTED:
            self.try_kill_host()

            if self.state is State.DEATH:
                neighbors_nodes = self.model.grid.get_neighbors(self.pos, include_center=False)
                neighbor_agents = [neighbor for neighbor in self.model.grid.get_cell_list_contents(neighbors_nodes)]
                agent_neighbor_pairs = [(self.unique_id, neighbor.unique_id) for neighbor in neighbor_agents]
                self.model.G.remove_edges_from(agent_neighbor_pairs)

    def step(self):
        if self.state is State.INFECTED:
            self.try_infect_neighbors()
        self.try_check_death()
        self.try_check_infection()
```

`model_network.py`

```
import math
import sys
import networkx as nx

from mesa import Model
from mesa.time import RandomActivation
from mesa.datacollection import DataCollector
from mesa.space import NetworkGrid

from .model_state import State, number_infected, number_susceptible, number_resistant, number_state, number_death
from .model_agent import HostAgent

class HostNetwork(Model):
    """A virus model with some number of agents"""

    def __init__(self, num_nodes=0, avg_node_degree=0, initial_outbreak_size=1, chance_spread_virus=0.0,
                    virus_check_frequency=0.0, chance_recovery=0.0, chance_gain_resistance=0.0,
                    chance_virus_kill_host=0.1, chance_severe_condition=0.0):

        # Some assert statement to make sure some chances together don't add up > 1.0

        self.num_nodes = num_nodes
        prob = avg_node_degree / self.num_nodes
        self.G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(n=self.num_nodes, p=prob)
        self.grid = NetworkGrid(self.G)
        self.schedule = RandomActivation(self)
        self.initial_outbreak_size = initial_outbreak_size if initial_outbreak_size <= num_nodes else num_nodes
        self.chance_spread_virus = chance_spread_virus
        self.virus_check_frequency = virus_check_frequency
        self.chance_recovery = chance_recovery
        self.chance_gain_resistance = chance_gain_resistance
        self.chance_virus_kill_host = chance_virus_kill_host
        self.chance_severe_condition = chance_severe_condition

        self.datacollector = DataCollector({"Infected": number_infected,
                                            "Susceptible": number_susceptible,
                                            "Resistant": number_resistant,
                                            "Death": number_death,
                                            })

        # Create agents
        for i, node in enumerate(self.G.nodes()):
            agent = HostAgent(i, self, State.SUSCEPTIBLE, self.chance_spread_virus, self.virus_check_frequency,
                                self.chance_recovery, self.chance_gain_resistance, self.chance_virus_kill_host,
                                self.chance_severe_condition)
            self.schedule.add(agent)
            # Add the agent to the node
            self.grid.place_agent(agent, node)

        # Infect some nodes
        infected_nodes = self.random.sample(self.G.nodes(), self.initial_outbreak_size)
        for agent in self.grid.get_cell_list_contents(infected_nodes):
            agent.state = State.INFECTED

        self.running = True
        self.datacollector.collect(self)

    def resistant_susceptible_ratio(self):
        try:
            return number_state(self, State.RESISTANT) / number_state(self, State.SUSCEPTIBLE)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return math.inf

    def step(self):
        self.schedule.step()
        # collect data
        self.datacollector.collect(self)

    def run_model(self, n):
        for i in range(n):
            self.step()
```

`server.py`

```
import sys
import math

from mesa.visualization.ModularVisualization import ModularServer
from mesa.visualization.UserParam import UserSettableParameter
from mesa.visualization.modules import ChartModule
from mesa.visualization.modules import NetworkModule
from mesa.visualization.modules import TextElement

from .model_network import HostNetwork
from .model_state import State, number_infected, number_susceptible, number_resistant, number_death


def network_portrayal(G):
    # The model ensures there is always 1 agent per node

    def node_color(agent):
        return {
            State.INFECTED: '#FF0000',
            State.SUSCEPTIBLE: '#008000',
            State.DEATH: '#000000',
        }.get(agent.state, '#00C5CD')

    def edge_color(agent1, agent2):
        if State.RESISTANT in (agent1.state, agent2.state):
            return '#000000'
        return '#e8e8e8'

    def edge_width(agent1, agent2):
        if State.RESISTANT in (agent1.state, agent2.state):
            return 1
        else:
            return 3

    def get_agents(source, target):
        return G.nodes[source]['agent'][0], G.nodes[target]['agent'][0]

    portrayal = dict()
    portrayal['nodes'] = [{'size': 6,
                           'color': node_color(agents[0]),
                           'tooltip': "id: {}<br>state: {}".format(agents[0].unique_id, agents[0].state.name),
                           }
                          for (_, agents) in G.nodes.data('agent')]

    portrayal['edges'] = [{'source': source,
                           'target': target,
                           'color': edge_color(*get_agents(source, target)),
                           'width': edge_width(*get_agents(source, target)),
                           }
                          for (source, target) in G.edges]

    return portrayal


network = NetworkModule(network_portrayal, 500, 500, library='d3')
chart = ChartModule([{'Label': 'Infected', 'Color': '#FF0000'},
                     {'Label': 'Susceptible', 'Color': '#008000'},
                     {'Label': 'Resistant', 'Color': '#00C5CD'},
                     {'Label': 'Death', 'Color': '#000000'},
                     ])


class MyTextElement(TextElement):
    def render(self, model):
        ratio = model.resistant_susceptible_ratio()
        resistance_susceptible_ratio_text = '&infin;' if ratio is math.inf else '{0:.2f}'.format(ratio)
        infected_text = str(number_infected(model))
        susceptible_text = str(number_susceptible(model))
        resistant_text = str(number_resistant(model))
        death_text = str(number_death(model))

        return "Resistant/Susceptible Ratio: {}\
                <br>Infected Number: {}\
                <br>Susceptible Number: {}\
                <br>Resistant Number: {}\
                <br>Death Number: {}\
               ".format(resistance_susceptible_ratio_text, infected_text, susceptible_text,
                        resistant_text, death_text)


model_params = {
    'num_nodes': UserSettableParameter('slider', 'Number of agents', 10, 10, 300, 1,
                                       description='Choose how many agents to include in the model'),
    'avg_node_degree': UserSettableParameter('slider', 'Avg Node Degree', 2, 1, 8, 1,
                                             description='Avg Node Degree'),
    'initial_outbreak_size': UserSettableParameter('slider', 'Initial Outbreak Size', 1, 1, 100, 1,
                                                   description='Initial Outbreak Size'),
    'chance_spread_virus': UserSettableParameter('slider', 'Chance to spread virus', 0.4, 0.0, 1.0, 0.1,
                                                 description='Probability that susceptible neighbor will be infected'),
    'virus_check_frequency': UserSettableParameter('slider', 'Virus Check Frequency', 0.4, 0.0, 1.0, 0.1,
                                                   description='Frequency the nodes check whether they are infected by '
                                                               'a virus'),
    'chance_recovery': UserSettableParameter('slider', 'Chance to recover', 0.3, 0.0, 1.0, 0.1,
                                             description='Probability that the virus will be removed'),
    'chance_gain_resistance': UserSettableParameter('slider', 'Chance to gain resistance', 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.1,
                                                    description='Probability that a recovered agent will become '
                                                                'resistant to this virus in the future'),
}

server = ModularServer(HostNetwork, [network, MyTextElement(), chart], 'Covid-19 Model', model_params)
server.port = 8521
```

`self.model.G.remove_edges_from(agent_neighbor_pairs)` seems to give me troubles. What I am seeing is some duplicated nodes and edges similar (but not exactly the same) as the original graph.

One example:
[image]

Another example:
[image]

Comment: Which module or function call do creates the visualisation? (As far as I see you don't use the networkx drawing functions). My guess is that you don't fix the positions of the nodes at any time in your code, which results in different positions (after you remove the edges). Try your visualisation without all the other stuff around to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Yeah, I think the networkx is abstracted away by mesa. All the visualization is in the server.py. What "all other stuff" do you refer to? And how can the nodes be "fixed"?

Comment: A minimal example for your question would be two graphs visualised with `NetworkModule` and one time the full (simple) graph and a second time with one edge removed. You will see from https://mesa.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/mesa/visualization/modules/NetworkVisualization.html that your problem becomes a javascript problem, i.e. how to fix the position of nodes in sigma/d3.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. Can I get more clarity? So for me to remove the edge. Do I need to do all of the following actions? 1) remove the edge as in self.model.G.remove_edges_from() above, and 2) fix the node positions via js code in NetworkModule?